# Installing GnuPG on Solaris ---- failed

Tags: software-installation, solaris, gnupg

i have Solaris

**SunOS 5.10 Generic_147441-01 i86pc i386 i86pc Solaris**

trying to install GnuPG on it

i have referred these sites for it

http://gnupg.org/

http://www.blastwave.org/pkg/search.ftd?qs=gnupg     --- package build for Solaris

http://www.blastwave.org/jir/blastwave.fam  --- steps to install

in Steps to install , it gives error there no package as textutils

please guide me to install this on my Solaris box properly

Comment: before you can install `GnuPG` you have to resolve all dependencies, that `GnuPG` needs to run. So your first step would be to install `textutils`.

Comment: is there anything which can install all with its dependencies as well

Comment: I'm not a Solaris guy but i heard about `pkg-get` sometime ago which downloads packages and automatically resolve dependencies. With this keyword i found this site http://tutorialgenius.blogspot.de/2012/03/pkg-get-and-pkgutil-package-management.html, that talks about package management on Solaris. Another interesting site is: http://www.opencsw.org/manual/for-administrators/getting-started.html

Answer (score 2):

Ooops, ignore this as I just noticed you're using Solaris 10.  The below would be for people using v11 with the same question.

I can't get to the bastwave.org to see their steps for building and installing the package.  However it appears the tool is available via the support repo.

`% pkg info -r crypto/gnupg
             Name: crypto/gnupg
          Summary: GNU Privacy Guard
      Description: A complete and free implementation of the OpenPGP Standard as
                   defined by RFC4880.
         Category: Applications/System Utilities
            State: Not installed
        Publisher: solaris
          Version: 2.0.27
    Build Release: 5.11
           Branch: 0.175.3.0.0.30.0
   Packaging Date: August 21, 2015 04:15:09 PM
             Size: 7.12 MB
             FMRI: pkg://solaris/crypto/gnupg@2.0.27,5.11-0.175.3.0.0.30.0:20150821T161509Z`

So you should be able to install with:
`pkg install crypto/gnupg`

Comment: blastwave.org shut down a couple of years ago - it's no longer an option.